# Installing Jupyter with pip under Catalina

Tags: pip, jupyter-notebook, macos-catalina

I can't seem to be able to run Jupyter on Catalina.

I did successfully run

```
pip3 install --user Jupiter
```

but the bin is not correctly placed

```
$ jupyter notebook 
zsh: command not found: jupyter
```

in the past the `--user` option put the bin in `~/.local/bin`, but such folder does not exist.

Does anyone know where the bin is supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured ir you, so I'll post an answer here in case it's useful to others.

Apparently it puts the binaries in `~/.local/bin/`

Add this to your PATH variable and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Atfer the "pip3 install", I found jupyter this way:

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3

$  ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/
total 472
...
-rwxr-xr-x  1 vito  admin    268 26 Jun  2018 jupyter
...

$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/jupyter
usage: jupyter [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]
               [--paths] [--json]
               [subcommand]
```